# How to bevel edges next to ngons?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I can't get an acceptable bevel, is there any way to fix it?

[image: Bevel, complex mesh]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an inner edge loop on the top side of the edge in order for the bevel tool to work properly.

You either need to:

1. Select all the vertical side faces and extrude outward along their normals

**OR**

2. Delete some of the top faces that connect to the corner
   edge. Then you can extrude the corner edge in slightly to achieve
   the inner edge loop.